# How to prevent np.where from turning 0 into '0'?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to create an array with np.where that has strings and 0s in it. So usually its dtype would be 'object'. Minimal example:

```
A = np.array([[1,2,1],[2,1,2],[1,1,2]])
x = np.where(A==1,0,'hello')
```

As a result I get

```
array([['0', 'hello', '0'],
       ['hello', '0', 'hello'],
       ['0', '0', 'hello']], dtype='<U11')
```

I would like those '0's to be 0s. Since np.where has no argument for dtype, I don't know how to do this except by replacing them afterwards. There has to be a better way to do this.

Comment: If `np.where` did have dtype, what type would you want it to be?

Comment: @matszwecja I meant an argument for defining the dtype of the resulting array. Like in `np.array` you can do something like `dtype='object'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an object array as first input values for `where`:

```
x = np.where(A==1, np.zeros_like(A).astype(object), 'hello')
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 'hello', 0],
       ['hello', 0, 'hello'],
       [0, 0, 'hello']], dtype=object)
```